# How to replace words with different case in PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a really big data frame and it contains a specific column "city" with multiple cities repeating but in different case, for eg -

```
***City***

Gurgaon
GURGAON
gurgaon
Chennai
CHENNAI
Banglore
Hydrabad
BANGLORE
HYDRABAD
```

.

Is there a way to replace all the same cities with different case, with a single name.

There are total 3k rows in each column, so manually it's not possible.

Edit -

The city column of the DF also contains cities like

```
'Gurgaon'

'GURGAON'

'gurgaon '          #there is a white space at the end
```

I want something so that they all change to the same name and the delimiter is also removed. So that the output is →

```
 'Gurgaon'
 'Gurgaon'
 'Gurgaon'        #no white space at the end
```

Thanks

Comment: `df['City'] = df['City'].str.capitalize()`

Comment: Do you wish to remove duplicate names?

Comment: Thanks, both of you helped. And no, I don't want to remove duplicate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `str.strip()` to remove trailing whitespaces, and then use `str.title()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'City':["Gurgaon",
                           "GURGAON",
                           "gurgaon",
                           "Chennai",
                           "CHENNAI",
                           "Banglore",
                           "Hydrabad",
                           "BANGLORE",
                           "HYDRABAD"]})
df['City'] = df['City'].str.strip()
df['City'] = df['City'].str.title()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       City
0   Gurgaon
1   Gurgaon
2   Gurgaon
3   Chennai
4   Chennai
5  Banglore
6  Hydrabad
7  Banglore
8  Hydrabad
```

Comment: Can you help me with the edited question too? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what i wanted. My bad, I didn't explain it properly.

Comment: @PushpakRuhil Updated. Tell me if I got it this time.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I figured it out too, though. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

First, change the cities to have the same format:

```
df.city=df.city.apply(lambda x: x.capitalize())
```

Then, remove duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

(I assume the rest of the columns are equal)